# Xcode 6 crashes while submit

Tags: xcode, crash, submit

I just loaded Xcode 6 GM seed. Now I want to submit an update of my app. 
Archiving works so far. But when I click "Submit", as soon as the upload loading bar appears Xcode crashes.

Do I need Yosemite?

I had to download the Application Loader from Apple because Xcode could not find it.

Comment: Were you able to submit the app using just application loader? I tried this and the build never showed in itunes connect.

Comment: I am with Yosemite and mine crashes in the same way. I actually think that I submitted two builds before upgrading from Maverics.

Comment: I'm having the same issue running mavericks.  I was able to submit my app using the application loader.  Would love to be able to submit from xcode, I have 23 more apps to submit.  :(

Comment: @Kyle note that you have to press the (+) button in the top left corner of the Build section on iTunes Connect to select the build after uploading it.  That tripped me up for a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks, that also tripped me up. It did however take about a half hour for it to actually show up in the builds list.

Comment: @Kyle Yes, I am able to submit the app using just application loader.

Comment: But how @dmur said I would love to be able to submit from Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed the official version from the App Store and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 4):

> Do I need Yosemite?

No. Mine crashed the same way, so i uploaded my app using Xcode 5.1. It worked fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Fabio, I actually think it does answer the question posed by the original poster.  Though it perhaps does not answer the question of why the crash occurs in the first place... but that's one for the Xcode developers to answer. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The Application Loader seems the only thing that works right now. Had the same problem, while uploading or even just validating.
Just export via Organizer and Upload via Application Loader helped.

Answer (score 2):

**I was faced same problem. Now it works fine.
Solution : Just accept new changed terms and condition from apple developer account and resubmit it.**

Comment: I really can't believe that they made it... It worked like a charm for me, but its too dumb to be real. Not a single notification saying that I need to review the terms...

Comment: Just to complement the answer.. I had to synchronise my accounts and re-Archive it to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Please Make sure you've accepted all of the new agreements & condition in the Member Center.

To check if you need to, you can go to the preferences -> accounts in XCode, and chose to view details of an account and attempt to refresh button. Here, XCode will warn you that you need to accept new agreements in the Member Center before you can refresh.

or just login to developer account and go to here https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make Xcode work, but I had to go to iTunes connect and start the process there first by going "My Apps" and clicking on the plus sign.  Fill in the info and hit save.  Then try submitting with Xcode and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here's my $0.02.

1) Xcode 6GM crashes every single time for me. I am running 10.9.4. I have no idea how widespread the issue is, but it is 100% repeatable for me. I cannot use Xcode 6 to submit apps for review.

The crash happens during the upload. I have submitted a RADAR report and given crash logs.

2) I was able to submit using the App Loader. Here's how you do that:

2.1) In the Organizer, after you have done the Archive, select the latest archive for submit.

2.2) Instead of "Submit," select "Export."

2.3) Select the first choice (App Store).

2.4) Open the Application Loader.

2.5) Select "Choose."

2.6) Select the .ipa that you just saved in the export.

2.7) That will work. You may get a message teling you that the API file is too big for analysis. I got that for all 9 of the apps I just submitted. In my case, I ignored it.

I think they rewrote the whole application load from scratch, and that Xcode is still buggy as hell.

They had a deadline, and rushed it. It shows.

I expect both the server (Web) component and Xcode to apply patches soon.

In my case, I'm quite annoyed, as I had to rush out a fix for the arbitrary decision they made to change the way that the CLLocationManager works, which broke all my location lookups. The fix is simple, but there will be a period of time when I receive hate mail from the users that upgrade to iOS 8, and the app stops working.

Joy.

Comment: Just FYI: Apple seems to have fixed this in 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When XCode crashes during export or submit it means that you have non-valid certificate or provision profile in build settings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

1. Accept new changed terms and condition from [apple developer account](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action). (Just like Sandeep said)
2. Go to [here](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action) to generate new provision profiles, for App Store & AdHoc ([Tutorial](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/iphone6-6-and-ios8-xcode6-first-hand-on-experience-with-unity.269422/))
3. Double click new provision profiles you downloaded to install them, and then XCode will never crash.

The problem is caused by XCode 6.0 does not handle provision profile migration properly. Developers should regenerate provision profiles for XCode 6+, but Xcode 6.0 fails to display this error message properly and crashes. (If you use XCode 6.1 Beta, it will display error messages for you, no crash. Then you will know that the problem is caused by "invalid"=="legacy" provision profile.)

After that, you can submit app and export Ad Hoc distribution for Testflight.